# High IOWait executing JBoss 3.2.7

Tags: jboss, iowait

Server Details:
**Kernel:** Linux wiq31 2.4.21-9.ELsmp #1 SMP Thu Jan 8 17:08:56 EST 2004 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
**CPU:** 4 x Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.06GHz
**Memory:** 1028520 kB
**JBoss version:** 3.2.7

Every time i try to start JBoss, in all CPU's, the iowait values starts to raise and the idle values starts to fall.

Before executing my JBoss application, the *free* command returns the following output:

```
             *total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  
Mem:       1028520     966400      62120          0     187756     538928  
-/+ buffers/cache:     239716     788804  
Swap:      2044072     790672    1253400*
```

After starting my JBoss application, the *free* command returns the following output:

```
             *total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  
Mem:       1028520    1007648      20872          0     187116     524084  
-/+ buffers/cache:     296448     732072  
Swap:      2044072     819096    1224976*
```

After starting my JBoss application, without answering any request, the java process /proc/PID/status file have the following values:

```
State:  S (sleeping)
SleepAVG:       27%
Tgid:   24022
Pid:    24022
PPid:   21011
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    500     500     500     500
Gid:    500     500     500     500
FDSize: 256
Groups: 500
VmSize:   775200 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmRSS:    156752 kB
VmData:   696752 kB
VmStk:        36 kB
VmExe:        21 kB
VmLib:    710375 kB
StaBrk: 0804f000 kB
Brk:    095bb000 kB
StaStk: bffff8c0 kB
ExecLim:        ffffffff
Threads:        62
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
SigCgt: 1000000180015ccf
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
```

Is this behavior being caused by memory swapping, or the short memory available in the server is enough to run my application?

Answer (score 0):

Jboss will take up a pretty significant amount of memory on its own, even if you don't have anything running on it.

To see if your system is heavily swapping, you can always run

```
vmstat 1
```

and watch the output. Under "swap", you'll see "si" and "so"-- thos will be pages swapped in and out.

At a guess I would suggest more RAM, but you should really to move investigation first. For instance, if you have a lot of big objects being deployed, you may just need to wait on jboss for a while to drag these objects off the disk.